# Mapping from set $A$ surjectively onto itself which is not injective.

Tags: group-theory, functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $A$ denote some arbitrary set. Is it possible to construct a non-injective mapping from $A$ surjectively onto itself? This is a relatively elementary question; however, it's a concept I've never had a concrete example for. If somebody could provide something quick, I would really appreciate it! Shockingly, I couldn't find any duplicate on this site...unless I'm not looking hard enough.

(Also, as far motivation is concerned: I am curious to determine whether the First Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem for Rings is an "if and only if" statement; i.e. $A\cong B$ if and only if $ker(\mu)=\{1\}$ for some ring homomorphism $\mu:A\to B$. It is for this reason I have chosen to include the tag of "group-theory" to this post.)

Comment: do you mean a map $A\to A$ which is surjective but not injective? And what is $\phi$ here?

Comment: @CSquared Sorry for the bad notation on my part! By $\phi$, I mean the null set (though I'm realizing that's not a correct statement; instead, it should be the trivial set...I'll fix that). And yes, I'm looking for a mapping from $A\to A$ which is surjective and not injective. I realize the "onto itself" part might not be immediately clear, again I can fix.

Comment: why not use $\{\}$ ({}) or $\emptyset$ (\emptyset) or $\varnothing$ (\varnothing) instead? It will be less ambiguous in the future. You can also use \ker for typesetting $\ker$.

Comment: also the statements as you have written are not equivalent. $A\cong B$ says that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as rings, but the second statement says that $A$ is isomorphic to a subring of $B$

Comment: @CSquared Thanks for the tip on notation: I'm still relatively new with LaTeX, so I do appreciate it. Regarding the discrepancy in meaning, you could interpret the initial question as a non-injective surjective from $A\to B$ or $A\to A$; either way is fine.

Comment: just for fun, $\LaTeX$ (\LaTeX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean, can we have a surjection $A\to A$ that is not injective. Then the answer is yes. By counting reasons, you need that $A$ is infinite, but then it is always possible.

For a simple example, take $\Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{N}$ given by $n\mapsto \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$, i.e. we map $1$ and $2$ to $1$, $3$ and $4$ to $2$, $5$ and $6$ to $3$ and so on.

For your second question, it is true that two rings $G,H$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists a surjective ring homomorphism $\mu:G\to H$ with trivial kernel. But note that it does *not* mean that for two isomorphic rings $G,H$, any surjective homomorphism must have trivial kernel, or that any homomorphism with trivial kernel must be surjective.

As an example of the latter, consider $\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}$ given by multiplication by 2. This is a group homomorphism (admittedly not a ring homomorphism but you get the idea), and it must be injective, i.e. trivial kernel, but its image are all the *even* integers, so it is not surjective.

Comment: Multiplication by 2 is not a ring homomorphism though

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Good catch, thanks.

Comment: @LukasHeger no, this is an example for groups, chosen for simplicity. If you have a nice example for rings, feel free to share :)

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Take the ring of polynomials in infinitely many variables and map $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ for an injective map that is not surjective. It has a left inverse that is surjective but nor injective.

Comment: For a ring homomorphism example one can take $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ and map $x_1\mapsto 0,x_2\mapsto x_1,x_3\mapsto x_2 \ldots $. This doesn't look nice, but one can show that any example cannot be Noetherian, so that's to be expected

Comment: is it not enough to just embed a ring $R$ into $R[x]$?

Comment: The map $R[x] \to R[x], x\mapsto x^2$ is a simpler example of an injective endomorphism that is not surjective

Answer (score 0):

> **Theorem.** Let $A$ be a set. Consider the following statements:
>
> 1. $A$ can be bijected with a proper subset of itself.
> 2. There exists a function $f\colon A\to A$ that is one-to-one but not surjective.
> 3. There exists a function $g\colon A\to A$ that is surjective but not injective.
>
> Then 1 is equivalent to 2, and 1 implies 3. If we assume the Axiom of Choice, then 3 implies 2 (and hence 1).

*Proof.* 1$\implies 2$. Let $B\subseteq A$, $B\neq A$, and assume that $h\colon A\to B$ is a bijection. If $i\colon B\to A$ is the subset inclusion, then $f=i\circ h$ is one-to-one but not surjective.

2$\implies$ 1. Let $f\colon A\to A$ be one to one and not surjective, and let $B=f(A)$. Then $B$ is ap roper subset of $A$, and the co-restriction of $f$ to $B$ (that is, the map $h\colon A\to B$ given by $h(a)=f(a)$ for all $a\in A$) is a bijection of $A$ with a proper subset of itself.

1$\implies$3. Let $B\neq A$ be a proper subset of $A$ (which means $A\neq \varnothing$) and a bijection $h\colon A\to B$. Let $a_0\in A$, and define $g\colon A\to A$ by
$$g(a) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
h^{-1}(a) &\text{if }a\in B,\\
a_0 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.$$
Then $g$ is surjective, since $h^{-1}(B)=A$; and it is not injective: given any $x\in A$, $x\notin B$ (which exists since $B$ is a proper subset of $A$), we have
$$g(x) = a_0 =  h^{-1}(h(a_0)) = g(h(a_0)).$$
But $h(a_0)\in B$ and $x\notin B$, so $h(a_0)\neq x$. Thus, $g$ is not injective.

Finally, assume the Axiom of Choice, and let $g\colon A\to A$ be a function that is surjective but not injective. By the Axiom of Choice, every surjection has a right inverse $h$, so there exists $h\colon A\to A$ such that $g\circ h  = \mathrm{id}_A$. Let $B=\mathrm{Im}(h) = h(A)$. Note that because $g\circ h$ is bijective, then $h$ is injective, so $h\colon A\to B$ is a bijection. In addition, $B\neq A$: indeed, let $a,a'\in A$ be such that $g(a)=g(a')$. If $a$ and $a'$ are both in $B$, then there exist $u,v\in A$ such that $h(u)=a$, $h(v)=a'$. Then
$$u = g(h(u)) = g(a) = g(a') = g(h(v)) = v,$$
so $a = h(u) = h(v) = a'$. Now let $a,a'\in A$ be such that $a\neq a'$ and $g(a)=g(a')$ (possible, since $g$ is not injective). Then either $a\notin B$ or $a'\notin B$ (or both). So $B\neq A$. Thus, $A$ can be bijected with $B$, which is a proper subset of itself. $\Box$

Note that statement 1 is often taken to be the definition of "infinite set" (or more precisely, of a [Dedekind infinite set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set)). Assuming the Axiom of Choice, such functions exist if and only if the set $A$ is infinite.